# How to format a Double when format is variable?

Tags: c#, formatting

I have a method that takes in 2 numbers. The first number is the value that I want to set (or format) and the second number is the precision to use.

```
public double ReduceNumber(double Test, int Precision)
{
}
```

Let's say I pass in the parameters `125.6023867` and `4`. I would like the return value to be **`125.6023`**. I know how to use the `FormatNumber()` function in VB but now that I am trying to convert to C# I am drawing a blank. All that I can find online is `String.Format()` which helps but I don't know how to code for a format that can change regularly.

Comment: Do you need a `string` or a `double` to be returned?

Comment: "Reduce" is confusing.  Either you are modifying the value of the number, in which case you should use `Math.Round()`, or you are creating a string representation of the number for display, in which case you should use `double.ToString()`.

Comment: There are a few stylistic issues with your method: 1) The parameter names should be lowerCase. 2) I'd rename `precision` to something like `fractionalDigits`, since with I'd understand `precision` as the total number of digits. And the method should have a better name too. 3) You shouldn't return `double` when you care about decimal representation. There is a `decimal ` type for that.

Comment: @phoog I just created this as a very simple example.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I appreciate the advice. I'm new to programming and have my sights on reading some of the fundamental books. Sadly I'm nearly a grad student in IS (sorry!) and we don't learn some of these techniques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A formatted string:

```
public string ReduceNumber(double Test, int Precision)
{
    return Test.ToString(string.Format("F{0}", Precision));
}
```

This is using the [standard numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) "F" with a precision specifier.

A rounded double:

```
public double ReduceNumber(double Test, int Precision)
{
    return Math.Round(Test, Percision);
}
```

A point about style - parameter names are normally pascalCase in C#.

Answer (score 0):

here is something you can try it's' a simple method I wrote that adds "," to numbers like 10000 which would return 10,000 
also look up using string.Format{"0:d"} for example
this is just an idea I am also aware I didn't add percision but that could be passed in to the method as well...

```
   public static string FormatNumberWithCommas(string inputString)
   {
       string tempString;
       tempString = string.Format("{0:###.####}", Convert.ToInt32(inputString));
       return tempString;
   }
```